# Have I linked up this HTML and JavaScript file correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a small exercise in W3Schools that I wanted to try in my browser. The toggle animation did not work when I set the files separately, but it worked when I put the script within the HTML. Am I linking up the files wrong when they are separate? I also tried placing the script between the `<head>` tags, and that didn't work either.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(x)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction(x){
    x.classList.toggle("change")
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you want your JS function to be available in the HTML, you need to define it first. E.g. put your `script` tag in the `head` section. On a side note, using JS directly in the HTML code is generally bad practice, as it's harder to maintain on larger code, and can lead to that kind of mistakes. W3C does it here because they are just small demos, hence, they make them as short and simple as they can.

Comment: @blex Shouldn't matter, JS in attributes is not executed immediately.

Comment: @Hawkeye They are using the native [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) `toggle` method, not the jQuery toggle.

Comment: Your real problem looks like `x` is `undefined`, perhaps you mean to call it like `onclick="myFunction(this)"`. I strongly recommend avoiding JS attributes though.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara the 'this' worked, without the need for the jquery api, thank you

Comment: @tombros Sorry for the jquery suggestion. I thought you were using the jquery toggle not pure js `classList.toggle()`

Comment: Oh, BTW @blex, please don't refer to W3Schools as or being related to the W3C. They are completely unrelated entities, and W3Schools' name and knock-off branding is not sanctioned by the W3C.

Answer (score 1):

The tag

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="script.js"></script>
```

should suffice IF you saved the Javascript file as "script.js" in the same folder as your HTML file.

Also notice that the following line doesn't have a context for `x`:

```
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(x)">
```

Maybe you are trying to do something like:

```
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
```